# API REST retorna erro 500 no postman

Tags: java, spring, boot

```js
package com.example.Rest.Model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateSerializer;



@Document
public class Funcionarios {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private Integer cpf;
    private Double salario;
    private String email;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate dataContratacao;
    
    
    public Funcionarios() {
        
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return null;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(Integer cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public Double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(Double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public LocalDate getDataContratacao() {
        return dataContratacao;
    }

    public void setDataContratacao(LocalDate dataContratacao) {
        this.dataContratacao = dataContratacao;
    }

    
}





package com.example.Rest.Controller;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.Rest.Model.Funcionarios;

import FuncionariosServices.IFuncionariosService;




@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class FuncionariosController {
    
    
    private IFuncionariosService funcionariosService;
    
    

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Funcionarios> buscarPorId(@PathVariable String id) throws URISyntaxException {
        Funcionarios funcionarios = funcionariosService.buscarPorId(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Funcionarios>(funcionarios, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/cadastrar")
    public ResponseEntity<String> cadastrar(@RequestBody Funcionarios funcionarios) throws Exception{
        funcionariosService.cadastrar(funcionarios);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!", HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/listarnome")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>> buscarFuncionarios() throws URISyntaxException {
        List<Funcionarios> funcionariosList = funcionariosService.buscarFuncionarios();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>>(funcionariosList, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/buscarPorSalario")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>> buscarPorSalario(@RequestParam("salario") Double salario) throws URISyntaxException {
        List<Funcionarios> funcionarios = funcionariosService.buscarPorSalario(salario);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>>(funcionarios, HttpStatus.OK);
    } 
    
    @GetMapping("/dataContratacao")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>> dataContratacao(@RequestParam ("localdate")LocalDate localdate) throws URISyntaxException {
        List<Funcionarios> funcionarios;
        funcionarios = funcionariosService.datacontratacao(localdate);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Funcionarios>>(funcionarios, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
}




package FuncionariosServices;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.Rest.Model.Funcionarios;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.request.GetRequest;
import com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequest;
import com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody;



@Service

public class FuncionariosService implements IFuncionariosService {
    
    private List<Funcionarios> funcionariosList;

    @Value("${demo.mvc.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;    
    
    
    public Funcionarios buscarPorId(String id) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            HttpRequest response = Unirest.get(endpoint + "/buscarPorId" + id);
            return (Funcionarios) response.getBody();
            
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    public Funcionarios cadastrar(Funcionarios funcionarios) throws URISyntaxException {
        try { 
            HttpRequestWithBody response = Unirest.post(endpoint + "/cadastrar" + funcionarios);
            return (Funcionarios) response.getBody();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            
          return null;

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Funcionarios> buscarFuncionarios() throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            Funcionarios funcionarios = (Funcionarios) this.buscarFuncionarios();
            GetRequest response = Unirest.get(endpoint + "/buscarFuncionarios" + funcionarios);

            return (List<Funcionarios>) response.getBody();

        }catch (Exception e) {

          return null;
        }

    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Funcionarios> buscarPorSalario(Double salario) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            GetRequest response = Unirest.get(endpoint + "/buscarPorSalario" + salario);
            
            return (List<Funcionarios>) response.getBody();
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
            return null;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public List<Funcionarios> datacontratacao(LocalDate localdate)throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            List<Funcionarios> funcionarios = this.datacontratacao(localdate);
            Unirest.get(endpoint + "/buscarDataContratacao" );
            
            return  (List<Funcionarios>)(funcionarios);
        
        }catch (Exception e){
            
            return null;        }
    }

    public List<Funcionarios> getFuncionariosList() {
        return funcionariosList;
    }

    public void setFuncionariosList(List<Funcionarios> funcionariosList) {
        this.funcionariosList = funcionariosList;
    }

    
}
```

Olá,

Desenvolvi uma API, de cadastro de funcionais, onde eu preciso fazer que a chamada Rest indenize os mesmos dados da primeira API. No postman retorna o erro 500:

```
"timestamp": "2022-06-02T21:05:40.861+00:00", "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error", "trace": "java.lang .NullPointerException: Não é possível invocar "FuncionariosServices.IFuncionariosService.buscarFuncionarios()" porque "this.funcionariosService" é null\r\n\tat com.example.Rest.Controller.FuncionariosController.buscarFuncionarios(FuncionariosController.java:48)\r\n \tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\ tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que `funcionariosService` dentro do seu controller é null, como diz na mensagem de erro.
Você declarou uma variável, mas não inicializou ela com nenhum valor, o que deveria estar dentro de `funcionariosService`?

O método "comum" de se criar este tipo de dependencia seria:

```
FuncionarioService funcionarioService = new FuncionarioService();
```

Como você está usando Spring e já declarou que FuncionarioService é um Bean usando @Service, você pode delegar a injeção ao Spring, apenas anotando a dependencia com @Autowired

```
@Autowired
private FuncionarioService funcionarioService;
```

OU da seguinte forma se estiver usando lombok

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NameClass {

private final FuncionarioService funcionarioService;
```

a segunda opção é mais recomendada visto que a notação @Autowired já é considerada depreciada

Recomendo pesquisar sobre Injeção de Dependêndencias para saber mais a respeito.

Comment: Muito obrigada Leonardo! Me ajudou bastante.